# libgdx добавление красивой кнопки)

Tags: java, libgdx

ну у меня получилось добавить кнопку, но смотря на код и в диспетчер задач есть подозрение, что я сделал что-то не так.
Кто-нибудь может объяснить, как добавить кнопку с изображением, изменением самого изображения при нажатии и вызовом метода, соответственно, учитывая, что все нажатия обрабатываются в классе Control, спасибо

Comment: Есть много способов, самый распространенный - использовать скины. Но есть и другие. Распишу про скины, ближе к вечеру/завтра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cкины в Libgdx.**

Скины это расширение **Scene2D** для более удобного управления интерфейсом. 
Это расширение мы и будем использовать для создания красивой кнопки:) (но можно 
и не только для кнопки). Каждый виджет из **Scene2D** имеет вложенный класс стиля (например, возьмем **ImageButton**, если посмотреть внутрь этого класса, в нем будет класс стиля **ImageButtonStyle**.

Класс стиля виджетов описывает, как будет выглядеть виджет в разных ситуациях, например, когда мышка находится над ним.

Вернемся к скинам. Скины - это скрипты, которые описывают стили используемых виджетов. Чтобы создать скин, создайте json файл (например, ***defaultUI.json***) в папке ***assets/skins***.

Далее впишите туда следующее:

```
{
  "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle": {
    "default-button":
    {
      "imageUp": "default_button_up",
      "imageOver": "default_button_over" 
    }
  },
}
```

Теперь опишу, что это значит.

***"com.badlogic.gdx....."*** - путь к стилю, который вы хотите использовать. Если вам нужна кнопка - картинка, то вы будете использовать стиль из примера.

***"default-button"*** - это название стиля. Оно будет нужно в коде, чтобы придать кнопке стиль.

***"imageUp и imageOver"*** - это сами значения стиля. Им задаются картинки, которые назначаются в разных ситуациях. Например, "imageUp": "default_button_up" - использовать картинку с именем default_button_up по дефолту для кнопки. "imageOver" - то, какую картинку использовать, если мышка над вашей кнопкой. Какие еще можно использовать параметры - гугл в помощь. Для кнопки все параметры [тут](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.ImageButtonStyle.html).

Теперь, когда мы создали скин, нам нужно создать атлас с картинками для скина. Я этот момент опущу, тк думаю вы уже сами знаете, как делать атласы, но если что - пишите, дополню ответ.

Когда мы создали атлас и скин, нам нужно их связать в коде. Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
 public static TextureAtlas DEFAULTUI_TEXTUREATLAS = new TextureAtlas("тут путь к атласу, пример (skinAtlas.atlas)";
 public static Skin DEFAULTUI_SKIN = new
 Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skins/defaultUI.json"), DEFAULTUI_TEXTUREATLAS);
```

На этом всё, можно использовать скин. Пример создания кнопки:

```
ImageButton menuButton= new ImageButton(DEFAULTUI_SKIN, "default-button");
```

Если какой-то этап не понятен, пишите, дополню ответ. Примерно так делается интерфейс в Libgdx.